# Passing array as a function parameter and use it

Tags: php

I have two files - `file1.php` and `functions.php`.

What I'm trying to do is from `file1.php` to pass an array which to use in a `functions.php`. Here is what I mean

In `file1.php`

```
if(  $_GET['page'] ==  'index' )  {

  if ($user_id) {

     $idsArr = array('1', '2', '3', '4');
     ....
     
     $users = calculate_users($year,$idsArr);
     $smarty->assign("users",$users);
  }
}
```

Then in `functions.php`

```
function calculate_users($idsArr, $year){
    global $DB;

    foreach ( $idsArr as $ids ) {
         $st = $DB->prepare('SELECT * FROM users WHERE id=?');
         $st->execute(ids);
         $user = $st->fetch();
    }          
}
```

When I `var_dump($idsArr);` god `NULL`.

So, how do I pass the array to the function when I open `index` page?

Comment: So where does `calculate_users` get called?  It takes `$idsArr` as parameter, so you need to pass the correct value in, in the place where you are calling this function.

Comment: @CBroe, in `file1.php`. I've added dots in the question but I've edited it now.

Comment: `function calculate_users($idsArr, $year)`, `$users = calculate_users($year,$idsArr)` - notice something ...? About the order ...?

Comment: Wait, what? I really didn't even think about that the order is important here. I'm really sorry.

Comment: Yes, the order is important. You named your function parameters and the variables the exact same here - but that is not a requirement. You could as well have a `function foo($a, $b)`, and call it with `foo($something, $otherthing)` - so PHP _can_ only tell by the order, which is meant to be which.

Comment: Now when you explain it I see the logic here. Sorry again, just started learning recently. And yes, it is working now when I re-ordered them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure you've all the code from the file1.php ?
You need to call the function that you want to execute so I'm guessing there should be an function call in the file1.php something like

```
$var_id = calcuate_users($idsArr, someyear?)
```

this would go to the function but sorry to say your question is not very clear.

Comment: And of course you have to include the functions.php-file in your file1.php: `require_once('functions.php');` and you have to return a value in the function else you always will get null.